# jQuery toggle name attribute and working with ne attribute

Tags: jquery

I try to toggle the name attribute on an button, and then toggle it back using a function that get called by the new name. Here my Code :

HTML

```
<button name="post">Post</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('button[name=post]').click(function(){

    $(this).attr('name','get');
    $(this).text('get');

});
$('button[name=get]').click(function(){

    $(this).attr('name','post');
    $(this).text('post');

});
```

and last but not least a **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DRUQt/)**

For one reason or another, the second function don't fire when the new name attribute is up, some pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use event delegation because you change the name of your button ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DRUQt/4/)).

Add a parent or use an existing one:

```
<div id="parent">
    <button name="post">Post</button>
</div>
```

And bind your events that way:

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'button[name=post]', function(){

    $(this).attr('name','get');
    $(this).text('get');

});

$('#parent').on('click', 'button[name=get]', function(){

    $(this).attr('name','post');
    $(this).text('post');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try this, which to me seems simpler

HTML

```
<button id="clickme" name="post">Post</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){ 
    if($(this).attr("name") == "post") {
        $(this).attr("name", "get");
        $(this).text("get");
    } else {
        $(this).attr("name","post");
        $(this).text("post");
    }

});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DRUQt/5/)

Comment: As I do alot of stuff inside, for readability puporses I prefer to use .on(). But indeed, it's also a nice way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are modifying attribute used as selector after bound event on element, new selector has no effect. 
Simple way should to delegate event to any static container in which your element is nested:

http://jsfiddle.net/DRUQt/6/

```
$(document).on('click','button[name=post]',function(){

    $(this).attr('name','get');
    $(this).text('get');

});
$(document).on('click','button[name=get]',function(){

    $(this).attr('name','post');
    $(this).text('Post');

});
```